# How to deliver hard 404's on angular app hosted on IIS using custom errors in web.config

Tags: angular, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service, angular-router

Right now to solve broken links on search results that have an old site cached we are using the default catch-all angular 404 technique.

```
  {
    path: '404', component: Error404Component
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: '404'
  }
```

I'm worried that since all of these dead links on search results now return a `status 200` instead of a `status 404` that google and bing will think these are still valid links and never update them.

My attempt to circumvent this was to have the IIS `web.config` catch the 404's then redirect:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <error statusCode="500" path="/" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404" />
</httpErrors>
```

With this code in the `web.config` and the `**` catch all route removed the site sits dead at 404's with no redirect. I am using Azure Web Apps serving static files from wwwroot with hash location strategy on.

What i'm looking for is a way to deliver hard 404's back to the client and redirect to a reasonable page for a good user experience while our site transitions from a static wordpress app to a SPA angular app.

Comment: @Machavity If i need to post there that's fine, but stack overflow specifically said to post this here if it involved editing .htaccess and the like. Not only does this do that it also involved angular router code. Give me a moment to copy this post and i'll head over to webmasters.

Comment: I couldn't just edit the SEO out without changing the meaning of the question. If you want to change it from asking how it will affect SEO I'm more than happy to reopen. Otherwise, Webmasters can help you with the SEO part

Comment: Done. This good?

Comment: Looks good. Voted to reopen